# ADMOB Memory Leaking?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, swift, admob

I'm using Swift language for ADMOB whenever new advertisement comes up, my Memory is increasing. I think there is a Leaking. Without ADMOB everything else is fine.

```
var inter: GADInterstitial
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    inter = GADInterstitial()
    inter.delegate = self
    inter.adUnitID = "****"
    var request:GADRequest = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [ "***" ]
    inter.loadRequest(request)
}
```

And I'm using UIActionAlert for displaying the Interstitial

```
self.inter.presentFromRootViewController(self)
```

Memory Report Link:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zjkt2f38rcy1ryr/Screenshot%202014-07-27%2020.17.18.png]

Am I doing something wrong? I'm using ARC. Can I force to release this `Interstitials` by myself.

**EDİT**:

I tried `GADBanner` too. I'm just opening the app; I'm not doing anything else and memory is increasing

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
 banner = GADBannerView()
 banner.delegate = self
 banner.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait
 banner.adUnitID = "****"
 var request:GADRequest = GADRequest()
 banner.rootViewController = self
 request.testDevices = [ "****" ]   
 self.view.addSubview(banner)
}
```

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gn3pq3s1w2gfdd/Screenshot%202014-07-27%2022.05.51.png]

Comment: I have the same problem with my App. Just starting the app and the memory fills up if the banner loads new ads. the same problem on my interstital ads, if i load a new one. it seems that the GADBannerView & GADInterstitalView never get cleaned up by ARC. It even stays on the same memory if I popToViewController. Anyone out there with a little trick?

Comment: Profile the app using the leak detector. Find out what object(s) is/are leaking and report back.

Comment: Kerim, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Minestroni-Soup , I didn't find it but i think the best way is writing your implementation with changing the source code. Their codes had problems 2 years ago.

Comment: The leaking are still here in 2017

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `destroy()` to avoid memory leaks on both banner and interstitial ads. Interstitial ads are one-time-use objects, so you would have to destroy them. Banner ads can be reused but once done using them, call `destroy()`.

[See this for reference](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/72).

Comment: this method no longer exists

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, although with GADInterstitial AdMob ads. HUGE CPU churn from the memory leak. The problem is that you have to go to your actual root view controller. I'm in Objective C, but basically, if you're in, say, a UITabBarController view hierarchy, then try this:

```
banner.rootViewController = (UITabBarController *)self.view.window.rootViewController
```

That one thing solved all of my issues. Hope it works!

Comment: When you want to destroy the banner, you can also do banner.rootViewController = nil :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to release the banner by setting delegate to nil.
From AdMob documentation (see https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/banner?hl=es):

> Note that if you implement your delegate as a distinct object rather
>   than a GADBannerView subclass you should be sure to set the
>   GADBannerView's' delegate property to nil before releasing the view.

```
- (void)dealloc {   
  bannerView_.delegate = nil;
   // Don't release the bannerView_ if you are using ARC in your project  
   [bannerView_ release];   
   [super dealloc]; 
  }
```

In your case I think you only need to implement the  `bannerView_.delegate = nil`  call.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It may help, but I actually never releasing the view, this is the main view and an ads just eating all the memory, so in 10 minutes app crash because of memory issue. If disable ads, -- no leaks. So I know it's ads.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best practice is to allocate the GADBannerView only once, otherwise it will pile up in your memory.

My solution is to store my GADBannerView in a singleton class, and allocate it when the app's rootViewController loads (didLoad). Then you can use it anywhere without requesting again.

Comment: I do the same, and I have memory loss every time new banner get loaded